# Magento catalog search returns zero

Tags: magento, search, catalog

Magneto search returns zero, while I print the query and execute in PHPMYADMIN - enough product listed is coming . Below is my query:

---

```
SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `mg_catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `mg_catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '2' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `mg_catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='2' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2'
```

---

Thanks

Comment: Have you check your configuration for search result query?

Comment: I have tried with all combination in Configuration -> Catalog for Catalog Search

Comment: can you describe what you have try in site? means try to search.

Comment: Anything that is part of product name, description and even SKU. Quick search popup (div under search box) shows results but Search Page not.

Comment: You have used extension for search result pop-up? If yes then try to disable that extension and then check.

Comment: No plugin, autocomplete option I wanted to say. Product comes in Autocomplete but not in Search Result Page.

Answer (score 0):

If your Magento search is not working by displaying any results, the solution is right below.

Let’s assume that you already checked for product quantity, visibility, price, availability and all seems to be good.

You probably upgraded your Magento store or you have imported some products.

If yes, go to `System->Configuration->Catalog` and check that in Catalog Search the Search Type field is like.

That means that your product will be displayed if the searched keyword is anywhere in your product name.

example: keyword “can” and your product name is “Canon lens”.

If that didn’t solve your problem then go to System->Cache Management and clear your cache, or disable it.

If your problem still persists. Go to System->Index Management and reindex Catalog Search Index and all indexes that require indexing.
Check to see if the search works, if still not working there is one last thing that you can do to until you need professional's help.

Go to Catalog->Manage Products and select visible products.

Choose the Update Attributes action from the right panel and click Submit button.

Click on the Websites tab from the left and check the Main Website.

See the below URL:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwHYew8eQR5ubl9HNmsxaEhSRXBBMlJ5UFNhOFBMR3lZN3dz/view

Click Save button.

Now you must see your products that have their attributes updated into your search results.

Note: If you have a lot of products ( 6000, for example) and you select all products then you may still have the search problem (your products will not be assigned to your website).